# Is it backwards compatible to move protos to another file?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

For example if I cut and paste existing proto

```
message A {
  string b = 1;
}
```

from `/repo/protos/foo.proto` to `/repo/protos2/foo2.proto`

Is this ok to do? I realize `.pb.go`s will change. I'm trying to organize my protos, `foo.proto` is getting too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What matters are the types and field numbers. As long as that doesn't change, serialization and deserialization will be backwards compatible.